exception handling for using/StreamReader/var block
I'm unsure how to add exception handling for this area.  We had an exception in this, and I think we were unable to reach the file temporarily in the middle of the read. It was in this area, since it's the only StreamReader area.  I like the way it works, other than the issue of difficulty adding exception handling here, so don't want to change the overall flow.
Exception:

static IEnumerable<string> ReadAsLines(string filename)
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(filename))
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            yield return reader.ReadLine();
}

When I try catching the exception like the following, I get an error with yield,

Error CS1626  Cannot yield a value in the body of a try block with a
catch clause

static IEnumerable<string> ReadAsLines(string filename)
{
    try
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(filename))
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                yield return reader.ReadLine();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {

    }
}

Update:
I was thinking I can return something like 0 or null that I can handle and retry in the calling method, but again, not sure how to do that, since I can't put yield in the try, and not sure how to control what is returned from ReadAsLines. What I show in ReadAsLines has an error of

Error CS1622  Cannot return a value from an iterator. Use the yield
return statement to return a value, or yield break to end the
iteration.

static IEnumerable<string> ReadAsLines(string filename)
{
    try
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(filename))
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                yield return reader.ReadLine();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logMsg += "network Path not found for " + filename;
    }
    return null;
}

public static char DetectSeparator(string filePath)
{

    try
    {
        string[] lines = File.ReadLines(filePath).Take(1).ToArray();
        if (lines.Length == 0)
        {
            logMsg += "Could not detect separater lines";
        }
        return DetectSeparator(lines);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        logToEventViewer("Caught Exception Message: "+ex.Message + "Stack"+ex.StackTrace);
    }
    //static char c = '0';
    return c_default ;
}

static DataTable ReadDataTable(string filePath)
{
    char delimiter = DetectSeparator(filePath);
    if (delimiter == '+') //invalid////////////////////
        return null;
    if (delimiter.Equals(""))
        logMsg += "Delimiter was empty";
    var reader = ReadAsLines(filePath); //////////call to exception area
    var dataTable = new DataTable();
    int i = 0;

    //this assumes the first record is filled with the column names
    int h_ct = 0;
    var headers = reader.First().Split(delimiter); //split on tab, comma, semicolon
    if (ContainsCaseInsensitive(filePath,"Media_Multihead"))
        h_ct = reader.First().Count(ch => ch == '\t');
    

    foreach (var header in headers)
    {
        dataTable.Columns.Add(header);
    }

    foreach (DataColumn c in dataTable.Columns)
        c.ColumnName = String.Join("", c.ColumnName.Split());

    var records = reader.Skip(1);
    foreach (string record in records) //foreach var record in records
    {
        i++;
        int r_ct = record.Count(ch => ch == '\t');

        try
        {
            string tmp = "";
            if (/*(i >= 770) &&*/ ContainsCaseInsensitive(filePath,"Media_Multihead"))
            {
                //get rid of extra tab if needed
                if (r_ct > h_ct)
                {
                    tmp = (string)(record.TrimEnd('\t'));
                    dataTable.Rows.Add(tmp.Split(delimiter));
                }
                else
                {
                    dataTable.Rows.Add(record.Split(delimiter));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                dataTable.Rows.Add(record.Split(delimiter)); //split on tab, comma, semicolon
                                                             //var tmp = record.Split('\t', ',', ';');
                                                             //dataTable.Rows.Add(tmp); //split on tab, comma, semicolon
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex) 
        {
            try
            {
                CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
                DateTime rowDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(record.Split(delimiter)[0], "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm", provider);
                if (rowDateTime > DateTime.Today.AddDays(-2)) //only report issue if it's a date we care about
                {
                    logToFileAndScreen("***********************************");
                    logToFileAndScreen(ex.Message+ " " + ex.InnerException);
                    logToFileAndScreen("for close to this line:"+ i+ " File: "+ filePath  );
                    logToFileAndScreen("for this line: "+ record);
                    logToFileAndScreen("*************************************");
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex2)
            {
                if (!(ex2.Message.Contains("valid DateTime"))) 
                    logToFileAndScreen("Caught second exception "+ex2.Message+ " " +ex2.InnerException);
            }
        }
        
    }

    //logToFileAndScreen("Done reading file: {0}", filePath);
    if ((dataTable == null) || dataTable.Rows.Count == 0)
        logMsg += "dataTable is null or Row Count equals 0";
    return dataTable;
}

public static char DetectSeparator(string[] lines)
{
    var q = SeparatorChars.Select(sep => new
    { Separator = sep, Found = lines.GroupBy(line => line.Count(ch => ch == sep)) })
        .OrderByDescending(res => res.Found.Count(grp => grp.Key > 0))
        .ThenBy(res => res.Found.Count())
        .First();

    return q.Separator;
}

This is the method I'm using to find the delimeter.  I have different delimeters in different files I read, which is needed to read the log into a dataTable.  find delimeter

"I'm unsure how to add exception handling" if you don't know how to handle that exception why add a catch block? First define what should happen in the catch block. When you know that and can show us that we might have the right idea to actually do that.

for the record: blindly swallowing an exception is not "exception handling"

Why not just use File.ReadLines(filename) ?

File.ReadLines(filename) is already on his stack?

I added update, with more surrounding code and an idea of how I want to handle the exception, which has an error.

@MarcGravell - I need to get the delimiter info.  See added code. I'll try to find the example I'm using that I found online and add that info.

@MarcGravell I added the link at the end of the question above.

This code that just logs in the catch blocks and then swallows the problems and moves on doing what it does gives me chills. Don't went through the code complete but feels wrong and to complicated. If the csv file isn't large just read everything at once like using with File.ReadAllLines. And consider a working pre existing CSVReader that already handles most problems like CsvHelper even if you like how it works currently.

Just keep the risky code local so it can deal with mishaps, write ReadAsLines(StreamReader file)

IMO you should just use File.ReadLines here, but to generalize how to unroll this successfully - something like:
static IEnumerable<string> ReadAsLines(string filename)
{
    StreamReader reader;
    try
    {
        reader = new StreamReader(filename);
    }
    catch
    {
        yield break; // failed to open the file, treat as empty
    }
    try
    {
        string? s;
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                s = reader.ReadLine();
            }
            catch
            {
                // treat any failure as EOF
                s = null;
            }
            if (s is null) break;
            yield return s;
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        reader.Dispose();
    }
}


Not throwing FileNotFoundException at start, but anything during reading? Hmm..

@Sinatr fine; better?

Oh, I see what you're doing.  It's the same return type.  I just need to figure out how to get rid of the string? s part.  I have c# 7.3 and not 8.

@MarcGravell If you have any thoughts on how to use c# 7.3 that doesn't have string? available, feel free to chime in!

@Michele you can just use string. There would be no issues.

@Michele replace string? with string - that should be all

@MarcGravell Thanks! That's what I did a couple days ago.  I appreciate your help!
